# Organizing Core Data objects into sections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have the following data model:

[image: managed object structure]

After opening a document, I would like to list the layers (as sections) with the underlying objects in a `UITableView`.
I have implemented the fetched results controller the following way:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create the fetch request for the entity
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DB_Layer" 
        inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

    // Sort by stacking order, descending
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] 
        initWithKey:@"stackingOrder" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Create the fetched results controller, and set this controller to be the delegate
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
        initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
        sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Layer"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    // Fetch the results into the fetched results controller
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

The problem is that this gives me the list of *all* layers (even those belonging to other documents).
I believe I should use an `NSPredicate` to narrow down the results, but I am not sure how.

What I would need to have is:

- a list organized into sections by `DB_Layer` objects (I am not sure where I can specify what to group the results by)
- each section containing the objects/groups of the corresponding layer.

---

#### EDIT:

Based on Richard Casey's answer, I can now get the list of layers, but it requires me to retrieve *all* `DB_Shape` objects (even those belonging to other documents), and filter them with predicates.
This is a big performance hit.

What I am really looking for is a way to do it the other way around:

- pass the current document to the `NSFetchedResultsController`,
- retrieve the related objects, creating a section for each `DB_Layer`
  object,
- list the corresponding -- either grouped (`DB_Group`) or separate
  (`DB_Shape`) objects within the section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am really looking for is a way to do it the other way around:
>
> - pass the current document to the NSFetchedResultsController,
> - retrieve the related objects, creating a section for each DB_Layer object,
> - list the corresponding -- either grouped (DB_Group) or separate (DB_Shape) objects within the section.

A `NSFetchResultsController` can only return **one** kind of entity. So you cannot list both `DB_Group` and `DB_Shape` entities with the current model. The `DB_Group` entity shares all attributes with `DB_Shape` so you could make `DB_Shape` a subentity of `DB_Group`.

This way `DB_Layer` only has a one-to-many for `DB_Group` relation, that just so happen to include the shapes as well. You fetch request will then:

- Fetch `DB_Group` entities.
- Grouped by the `DB_Layer`.
- Filtered by a predicate based on the layers `DB_Document`.

For presentation you use `isKindOfClass:` if you need different view types for groups and shapes.

Comment: The problem is that `DB_Group` and `DB_Shape` don't _really_ share the same attributes: a group has its own name, and shapes within have their own, too. The stacking order of the group is within the layer, the shape's stacking order is within the group if it belongs to one; if not, it is the order within the layer. Not every shape belongs to groups, so I can't use inheritance.  With the method you're suggesting, I should retrieve the shapes (as Richard suggested), and work backwards from there -- I tried to avoid that for performance reasons: it would retrieve all the shapes of each document.

Comment: @antalkerekes - The *stacking order* is related to it's parent. A groups parent is the layer, a shapes parent is the group. If a Shape inherits from Group, there there is no problem to populate the *groups* relation ship with both groups and shapes, both *are* groups, think *"what would `isKindOfClass:` say?"*.

Comment: It took a while to realize, but you are right: conceptually, a shape is a group in itself, therefore inheriting from `DB_Group` _does_ make sense. And this also happens to solve the problem with the fetched results controller.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. To list layers for a particular document, you can use an NSPredicate.

The following code (added before you create your NSFetchedResultsController) should do it.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"document.name == %@",docName];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

The docName variable in the above code is the name attribute of the document you want to list.

When you create the NSFetchedResultsController, the sectionKeyNamePath parameter specifies the attribute that is used for generating groups for your tableview. If you want to list the objects/groups by the corresponding layer, you would probably want to have the NSFetchRequest run against the DB_Shape entity and then use @"layer.name" for the sectionKeyNamePath.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Listing the layers works correctly this way. I am working on getting the objects listed correctly. Your suggestion of fetching from DB_Shape is not really an option, as a DB_Layer can contain both groups and shapes -- although I could check if a given shape belongs to a group, and organize the results list accordingly.

Comment: You could skip the name step and just do `…@"document == %@", document`. Where document can be an `NSManagedObject` instance, or the managed object ID.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the answer to your question but if you have a specific `DB_Document` object in hand, then you don't have to fetch you just ask the object for the contents of it's `layer` relationship and then go from there.

That's rather the whole point of having relationships. You already know what objects you need and you don't have filter the entire persistent store looking form them.

Comment: That is true, but I am setting up the fetched results controller after opening the document, and for that I need an initial fetch. That's why I'm fetching from the topmost child entity. 
What you're suggesting is - of course - a better way (and what I was originally aiming for), but I'm not sure how to do that. How can I fetch the layers from the DB_Document entity?

Comment: `aDB_Document.layers` will give you all DB_Layer objects related to a particular `DB_Document` instance. Then you can sort or filter them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the structure for your DB_Layer object looks like, but what you can do is modify the NSFetchedResultsController initialization as follows to specify the field within DB_layer you want to create a section on. For example, if you have a field called "field1" in your core data object that you want to section your results on, updating the sectionNameKeyPath should create sections for you:

```
// Create the fetched results controller, and set this controller to be the delegate
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] 
    initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
    managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext 
    **sectionNameKeyPath:@"field1"** cacheName:@"Layer"];
```

Using a predicate will filter your results - not sure that is what you are after. The above snippet should group your results into sections based on "field1".